Data does not get saved in SQL Server database using ASP.NET
I'm working on an ASP.NET webforms app which is for patient registration where ID and registration no should be unique and auto generated. My HTML and C# is code is running and no error is displaying but the real problem in saving data when i fill the form it shows no error whether the data is saved or not.
Here is the HTML markup:
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="Formtask.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .parent{
            align-items: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: contents;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 150px;
            width:contain;
        }
         .margin {
             border: 1px solid black;
             margin-bottom: 2px;
         }
         .button {
              background-color: lightblue;
              border: none;
              color: black;
              padding: 15px 32px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              font-size: 16px;
         }
         .div {
             
             height: 5px;
             align-items: center;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="parent">
        <div>
           First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" class="margin" style="text-indent:20px;margin-left:17px;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" class="margin" style="text-indent:20px; margin-left:19px;"/>
        </div>
        <div>
           Address: <input type="text" id="add" class="margin" style="text-indent:20px; margin-left:36px;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           Contact No.: <input type="text" id="ph" class="margin" style="text-indent:20px; margin-left:11px;"/>
        </div>
        <div>
           Date: <input type="date" id="date" class="margin" style="text-indent:20px; margin-left:58px;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
           Time: <input type="time" id="time" class="margin" style="text-indent:20px; margin-left:57px;"/>
        </div>
        <div>
           Age: <input type="text" id="age" class="margin" style="text-indent:20px; margin-left:62px;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           Status: <select id="st" style="margin-left:50px;"><option value="stable">Stable</option><option value="critical">Critical</option></select>

        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Submit" style="margin-left:250px; height: 34px; width: 111px; margin-top: 10px;"/></div>
        </div>
    
    </form>
</body>
</html>

This is the C# code:
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Formtask
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=LAPTOP-VN6JLQTP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=webform;Integrated Security=True;Trust Server Certificate=True                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO datain (FirstName, LastName, Address, ContactNo, Date, Time, Age, Status) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @ContactNo, @Date, @Time, @Age, @Status)";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", Request.Form["fname"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Request.Form["lname"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Request.Form["add"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", Request.Form["ph"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Request.Form["date"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", Request.Form["time"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Request.Form["age"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Request.Form["st"]);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            // Optionally, you can redirect the user to another page after submission
            // Response.Redirect("SuccessPage.aspx");
        }
    }
}

Here is the SQL query:
CREATE DATABASE webform;

CREATE TABLE datain 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    PatientRegistrationNo NVARCHAR(50) 
         DEFAULT CONCAT('REG', REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), NEWID()), '-', '')),
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
    LastName NVARCHAR(50),
    Address NVARCHAR(100),
    ContactNo NVARCHAR(20),
    Date DATE,
    Time TIME,
    Age INT,
    Status NVARCHAR(50)
);

SELECT * FROM datain;

Please help me solve this problem.
Thanks!

I do not see any try/catch blocks to capture the error.  Have you stepped through to make sure your code actually gets to the Execute SQL CMD?  D  o you have data for all the fields/values?  Are you even connecting to the DB?

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

The code, as shown here, won't even compile because of the missing closing double quote on your connection string value.

and the submit button not tied to the button click code event, so it will not run when you hit that btn element anyway. This begs the question as to why server side controls are not being used here?

@Filburt it is closed, there are just a lot of spaces at the end of the connection string.

What links the submit button to the btn event handler in the code behind? Normally the HTML would use something like <asp:button onclick="btn" runat="server" ... />.

WebForms is old and outdated. You really should be looking at a more modern ASP.net implementation (and I'm a WebForms guy since they came out). If you are going to persist with Webforms, actually use them as they are designed be be used with server side controls and proper post back handling.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should use server side controls.
Hence this markup:
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    First Name:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
        ID="fname" class="margin" Style="text-indent: 20px; margin-left: 17px;">
    </asp:TextBox>


    Last Name:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
        ID="lname" class="margin" Style="text-indent: 20px; margin-left: 19px;">
    </asp:TextBox>

</div>
<div>
    Address:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
        id="add" class="margin" style="text-indent: 20px; margin-left: 36px;" >
    </asp:TextBox>

Contact No.:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
        id="ph" class="margin" style="text-indent: 20px; margin-left: 11px;">
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
    Date:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
        id="date" TextMode="Date"
        class="margin" style="margin-left: 58px;" >
    </asp:TextBox>
Time:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
        id="time" TextMode="Time"
        class="margin" style="text-indent: 20px; margin-left: 57px;">
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
    Age:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
        id="age" class="margin" style="text-indent: 20px; margin-left: 62px;"  >
    </asp:TextBox>


Status:
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server"
        id="st" style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <asp:ListItem>Stable</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Critical</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

</div>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" 
        Text="Submit"
        style="margin-left: 250px; height: 34px; width: 111px; margin-top: 10px;" 
        OnClick="btn_Click"
        />
</div>

And now the code behind becomes this:
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = 
        @"Data Source=LAPTOP-VN6JLQTP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=webform;Integrated Security=True;Trust Server Certificate=True";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = 
            @"INSERT INTO datain 
            (FirstName, LastName, Address, ContactNo, Date, Time, Age, Status) 
            VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @ContactNo, @Date, @Time, @Age, @Status)";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = fname.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lname.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = add.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ph.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.Time).Value = time.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = age.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = st.Text;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

